# How to use ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance to create an instance of a typed HttpClient

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, httpclient

I need to create an instance of a typed HttpClient using ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(..).

The underlying goal is I want a test that proves the Polly resilience stuff, that is supposed to have been configured, remains configured (for a typed HTTP client). It is a bit goofy, but now that I'm stumped I really want to know how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
var httpClient = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<HttpClient>(serviceProvider, [ what parameters go here? ]);
```

From my attempts, I've always gotten

> *System.InvalidOperationException*: A suitable constructor for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.

Comment: Maybe you can create it using the `HttpClientFactory`. Getting the factory in a variable like `var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()` and use the get the client: `httpClient = httpClientFactory.Create('TheNameHere');`

Comment: @Cristian-ȘtefănițăScăueru I'm using a "typed" HttpClient and not a named HttpClient. Thanks though.

Comment: The [tag wiki for "httpclient"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpclient/info) shouts *"DO NOT USE"*.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer.

However I did determine, by digging through framework source, that a typed client is actually a named client. The name is the short name of the type (i.e. the class name).